# Add tracking code to WooCommerce Thank You page for a specific product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, customization

Is there a way to customize this code to include an "If" statement to pull in a specific product ID so the tracking script is only added to the thank you page for that product? Something like this:

```
/* Add tracking code to thank you page for Product ID 27490 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'my_custom_tracking' );

function my_custom_tracking( $order_id ) {

    // Lets grab the order
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    
    // This is the order total
    //$order->get_total();
 
    // This is how to grab line items from the order 
    $line_items = $order->get_items();

    // This loops over line items
    foreach ( $line_items as $item ) {
        // This will be a product
        //$product = $order->get_product_from_item( $item );
        $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
        if ( $product_id = "27490" ){  
            echo "<!-- Event snippet for Purchase Thank You Page for product 27490 -->
<script>
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'send_to': 'XXXXXX',
      'value': 1.0,
      'currency': 'USD',
      'transaction_id': ''
  });
</script>";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Sorry, but SO is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question.  Here is a good place to start - [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), and what specific problem you need help with. See the [ask] page for details on how to best help us help you.

Comment: Thanks Howard, I have edited the question. Is this better now?

Comment: Well... You might keep trying. `is_product` will never be true since it's the thank you page. You need to get the product in the order from the $order_id which is passed by the hook.

Comment: Ok, thanks Howard. I've edited my post for my latest snippet. It now inserts the code on all purchases, not just for Product Id = 27490, so I'm still doing something wrong.  Can you shed any light here?

Comment: Product ID should be an integer and not a string so leave off the quotation marks. Also to do a comparison you don't use = use === instead - so it should be `if (  27490 === $product_id  )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a clean solution to your question, this also puts the script in the footer, by passing your script to the `footer_script` enqueue.

You could also hook replace the entire sub-function `add_action( 'wp_print_footer_scripts',`

With `wp_add_inline_script( 'your-enqueued-script-handle', $script )` which would be cleaner.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'my_custom_tracking' );

function my_custom_tracking( $order_id ) {
    
    // Lets grab the order.
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
    
    // This is how to grab line items from the order.
    $line_items = $order->get_items();
    
    // This loops over line items.
    foreach ( $line_items as $item ) {
        if ( 27490 === $item->get_product_id() ) {
            $script = "gtag('event', 'conversion', {
                          'send_to': 'XXXXXX',
                          'value': 1.0,
                          'currency': 'USD',
                          'transaction_id': ''
                      });";
            add_action(
                'wp_print_footer_scripts',
                function() use ( $script ) {
                    echo '<!-- Event snippet for Purchase Thank You Page for product 27490 -->
                        <script>' . wp_kses_post( $script ) . '</script>';
                }
            ); // end of add_action to footer script.
        }
    }
}
```